# Script only by computer name

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to run command in script only if computer name start with XXX ?
like 01 / 02 / 03

The bat file I made is as follows, but the file does not work and closes. I wonder where am I going wrong.

```
@echo off

IF %COMPUTERNAME%== "01" (
    start_1.bat
) ELSE IF %COMPUTERNAME%== "02" (
    start_2.bat
) ELSE IF %COMPUTERNAME%== "03" (
    start_3.bat
) ELSE (
echo.
echo empty.
)
```

it worked like this

```
IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "01" (
 echo "%COMPUTERNAME%"
) ELSE IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "02" (
 echo "%COMPUTERNAME%"
) ELSE IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "03" (
 echo "%COMPUTERNAME%"
) ELSE (
 echo "%COMPUTERNAME%"
)
```

Comment: I've added spaces and double quotes but the file still closes.

Comment: No spaces, just quotes. `if "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="01"`

Comment: Run the script from the command prompt instead of double-clicking it so that the window stays open and you can clearly see it echo `empty`.

Comment: Thank you  SomethingDark, when I edited it the way you said, my file worked

Comment: Your `if`s check if `%computername%`  is *equal*  to `01` (etc), but not if it *starts*  with `01`. For that you need `if "%computername:~0,2%" == "01" ...`